# Pagination class in Custom Module in joomla

Tags: joomla

I am developing one custom search module in joomla. so I am using joomla's in-built database connection and function.

Problem is that I want to use pagination class in this module but don't know any hint.

Please help me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1: Get the total number of items in your database

```
ex: select count(*) from #__some_table where ....
```

Step 2: Import joomla pagination and create pagination object

```
jimport('joomla.html.pagination');
$pagination = new JPagination($total, $limitstart, $limit);
```

where 
$total = total number of items that you count in step 1
$limit = total number of items you want to display on a page
$limitstart = index of the first item in the page. For example if you have 20 items per page, 0 is start index for 1 page, 20 is start index for second and so on.

Step 3: Show pagination on your page

```
echo $pagination->getPagesLinks();
echo $pagination->getPagesCounter();
```